# Proving Algebra is Not a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently self-studying Rosenthal's "A first Look at Rigorous Probability Theory." I am stuck on $(b)$ of exercise $2.2.5$ (pp.$10$). The question is as follows:

> Prove that $\mathcal{B}_0$ is *not* a $\sigma$-algebra

where

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_0 := \{ \textrm{all finite unions of elements of } \mathcal{J} \}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{J} := \{ \textrm{all intervals contained in } [0, 1] \}.
\end{equation}

Intervals are by defined Rosenthal in the informal statement

> "intervals" is understood to include all the open/closed/half-open/single/empty intervals

Part $(a)$ of the question required showing that $\mathcal{B}_0$ is an algebra. I am pretty confident with my answer for this part, but I can't seem to produce a convincing answer to $(b)$. My work so far is to argue by contradiction, and assume that $\mathcal{B}_0$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} \{r\} = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \in \mathcal{B}_0,
\end{equation}
since the leftost term is a countable union of sets in $\mathcal{B}_0$. Whence
\begin{equation}
[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{Q} \cup [0,1])^c = \mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1] \in \mathcal{B}_0,
\end{equation}
by the closure of $\sigma$-algebras under complements. This is an uncountable set, and I suspect that it cannot be written as a **countable** union of elements of $\mathcal{B}_0$. However, I cannot formalize this thought. I would appreciate it if anyone could look over my proof, and tell me whether it can be salvaged. If not, I would appreciate a slight push in the right direction. Thanks!

---

EDIT #1 & #2: Changed subscript set operator from cup to cap in
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} \{r\} = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \in \mathcal{B}_0,
\end{equation}

Comment: Why should $\mathbb{Q}$ be in $\mathcal{B}_{0}$? There is surely no such requirement in the definition of sigma algebra?

Comment: Is the empty set a member of $\mathcal{B}_0$?

Comment: @AnyAD wrt your first comment, I am not claiming that $\mathbb{Q}$ is in $\mathcal{B}_0$. My logic was that the singletons are contained in $\mathcal{J}$, and thus in $\mathcal{B}_0$. Therefore, taking a countable union of the the rational singletons in $[0,1]$ should yield a set contained in [0,1].

Comment: @AnyAD wrt your second comment, yes. $\mathcal{B}_0$ is algebra, and therefore contains the empty set.

Comment: If by `single interval' you mean single point, then your reasoning looks good. I guess you are claiming that the complement of the rationals in the reals is uncountable. This is ok (otherwise assuming the converse, union of two countable sets would give an uncountable sets, giving a contradiction).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\ A=\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^n B_i$, with $\ B_i\in\mathcal{B}_0\ $, and if any $\ B_i\ $ is not a finite union of singleton sets, then $\ A\ $ must contain an irrational number.

**Edit:** As [FraGrechi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/348690/fragrechi) points out in a comment below, the original version of my answer was not accurate.

Comment: What if I take $A = \{0\} \cup \{1\} \cup \{.5, .7\}$? Each of these terms is in $\mathcal{B}_0$ (since $\mathcal{J}$ contains the singletons) yet $A$ does not contain an irrational number.